# Is there guidance for adding Uno 3 to existing UWP app?

Tags: uwp, uno-platform

I have an UWP app that is about to hit the store and I want to add Uno variants.  Is there guidance for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is!

- This is the guide for migrating UWP apps: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/migrating-apps.html
- This is the guide for migrating class libraries: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/howto-migrate-existing-code.html